# What is the difference between Jetpack and Jitpack in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, jitpack

While reading and watching videos of the android I thought `jitpack` and `jetpack` are similar things and I was pretty much confused to see a similar word with a different meaning. But I wanted to get a much clearer concept on it if anyone is willing to offer his `TIME` to help me differentiate them. I am a little bit nubee to Android. Thanks!

[image: JitPack-Android]  [image: JetPack-Android]

Comment: A google search would suffice here. Jitpack.io is package repository, like mavenCentral / jCenter. It's a place from where you get libraries. Android Jetpack is kind of a set of libraries created by Google for Android.

Comment: Yes @RickSanchez, that's what I am saying. As you said, they are both library sets. Or else the Jitpack.io is not created by Google and the Jetpack is created by Google. a little bit confusing. Thanks!

Comment: "A google search would suffice here" - and now a google search gives this page as the top result, and this page gives a clearer and simpler answer to the question than any of the other results. Well done team, the system is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jetpack is the brand name for a series of libraries and tools from Google to help developers use modern Android programming techniques.

Jitpack.io is a service for publishing libraries based on a GitHub repository.